# MySQL update query on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update my database its a soft delete on multiple row based in locationId

```
update device d
set d.deleteDate='2016-05-07'
where d.id in (select dtg.deviceId from devicestogroups dtg
               where dtg.groupId in (select g.id from `group` g
                                     where g.locationId ='1'));
```

When I run the query I get the error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Subquery will return me 2 records as I know because subquery returns two record update will not happen, but how do I solve this issue. I tried to solve but not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**, it would more better to use join instead of sub query with IN:

```
UPDATE device d
INNER JOIN devicestogroups dtg ON dtg.deviceId = d.id
INNER JOIN `group` g ON g.id = dtg.groupId
    AND g.locationId ='1'
SET d.deleteDate='2016-05-07'
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE device d
INNER JOIN devicestogroups dtg ON dtg.deviceId = d.id
INNER JOIN `group` g ON g.id = dtg.groupId
SET d.deleteDate='2016-05-07'
WHERE g.locationId ='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
update device set deleteDate='2016-05-07' 
where id in (select dtg.deviceId from devicestogroups dtg where dtg.groupId in ( select g.id from `group` g where g.locationId ='1'));
```

if you execute update not using alias on column to update

Comment: Thanks for your response but still the query fail to update for same reason

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
update d
set d.deleteDate='2016-05-07'
from device d
inner join devicestogroups dtg on d.id=dtg.deviceId
inner join `group` g on g.id =dtg.groupId
where g.locationId ='1'
```